# How to Show Row No in angular ui-grid 3.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I want to show the Row no in my grid.
I use cell template and there i use {{rowRenderIndex+1}}
It works fine when records are less then 14,but after record count get increased then when we scroll down the grid the Row No get initialize with one again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property in the data and add column for display:

```
//Add property
$scope.yourData.forEach( function(row, index){
  row.idx= index;
});


//Adding column
columnDefs: [
    {
        field: 'idx',
        displayName: '',
        width: 30
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [ui-grid FAQ](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20499%20FAQ%20Frequently%20Asked%20Questions) there is a section "*How can I show a sequence number/id in a column in my grid?*"

I believe you are looking for the second answer in that section:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)}}</div>'
```

The `rowRenderIndex` is used to index rows that are rendered at that moment.